# Translating LESS mixins to Sass

Tags: sass

Well.. Im a little familiar with LESS and when im trying to move up to SASS.

In less i create some framework this way:

```
.w(@x){width:@x;}
.h(@x){height:@x;}
.f(@x,@y){font:@x '@y'}
```

i save it framework.less and `@import` it on my main.less

I just searched but i didnt found how to do it in SASS.. Just read the docs in the official site but no success.
Can anybody explain me or send me a tutorial link? All the links i found on google was a little hard to understand even to make SASS work.

LESS' docs are very simple to understand but SASS is too complicated..

Comment: When you come back and work on this project in a year, are you going to remember what `f` stands for?  If the project is passed off to someone else, will it make sense to them?  These simple types of mixins don't save you any keystrokes in Sass and only serve to make the code more difficult to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called *mixins*.  You would write them like so:

```
@mixin w($x){width:$x;}
@mixin h($x){height:$x;}
@mixin f($x,$y){font:$x $y}
```

Mixin invocation looks like this:

```
.foo {
    @include f(1.5em, sans-serif);
}
```

However, your `f` mixin has redundant arguments:

```
@mixin f($x){font:$x}

.foo {
    @include f(1.5em sans-serif);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help! but do i have to use @include all the time? for example: `#content {@include w(150px); h(200px);} footer{@include w(100%); h(200px); f(10px arial);}`?

Comment: Yes, `@include` indicates that you're invoking a mixin.  If you're interested in avoiding that, you might want to consider using the older sass syntax instead of scss.

Comment: what do you indicate me? if scss is better i'll use it

Comment: My advice would be to avoid using mixins as a shortcut for a simple property/value combination.  There is no "better" when it comes to sass vs scss syntax, its all personal preference (though you will find that scss is more popular).

Comment: but should i use this way? `@mixin box($x, $y, $z){width:$x; height:$y; position: $z;}`